# cakephp read one to many

Tags: cakephp, one-to-many

I got relation One to many between Worker and Company.
In my WorkerModel:

> var $belongsTo = 'Firm';

In my FirmModel:

> var $hasMany = 'Worker';

In my FirmController I got function feed(id=null). I want to display all workers events that belong to this Firm like this:

> http: (...)/firms/calendar/1

I got:

> function feed($id=NULL) {
>
> $firm = $this->Firm->read(NULL,$id) ;
>
> $workers = $firm['Worker'] ;
>
> $conditions = array('Event.worker_id'=>$workers['0']['id'] );
>
> $events = $this->Event->find('all',array('conditions' =>$conditions));

This works well, but displays all events connected with first worker on $workers var.
How to write this query to populate all events connected with ALL workers that belongs to firm?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the relationships properly? Does Event belongTo Worker? Look at setting `$this->Firm->recursive = 2` just before your read and it should fetch them if the relationships are set up correctly.

Also look into the [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable).